# Migrating geometric network data to UPDM (2019) without linear referencing

Tags: esri-geodatabase, utility-network, utility-network-analyst, utility-and-pipeline-data-model

I have two databases storing pipeline data. One is spatial and the other is non-spatial. The spatial has one geometric network and other simple feature classes. I need to perform migration from those databases to one centralized database, Utility and Pipeline Data Model (UPDM) 2019. This is very simple data as it does not have any utility network or any linear referencing. I have seen the data template of UPDM. It has a utility network containing center-lines, calibration points etc. that are used for pipeline linear referencing.

Can I transform my data to UPDM without linear referencing?

Comment: Please do not [delete questions that have been closed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376878/can-i-migrate-geometric-network-data-to-updm2019-without-linear-referencing), and then re-ask them.  We need you to edit the original question so that those edits may be reviewed to determine if the question is ready to be re-opened.

Comment: I think people here should be more focused towards answering the question or helping rather than just closing, opening and  flagging the question. The previous was not as per @tour, therefore deleted and asked again. This question is clear, problem is clear, if someone really wants to help, s/he must answer it rather than pointing out irrelevant things.